# get the list and input from one function and run them in different function

Tags: python

i have a programm that generate the list and then i ask them to tell me what they want to do from the menu and this is where my problem start i was able to get the input form the user to different function but when i try to use the if else condition it doesn't check, below are my code

```
def menu(x,l):
    print (x)
    if x == 1:
        return make_table(l)
    if x == 2:
        y= input("enter a row (as a number) or a column (as an uppercase letter")
        if y in [ "1",'2','3']:
            print("Minmum is:",minimum(y,l))
    if x== 3:
        print ('bye')

def main():
    bad_filename = True
    l =[]
    while bad_filename == True:
        try:
            filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
            fp = open(filename, "r")
            for f_line in fp:
                f_str=f_line.strip()
                f_str=f_str.split(',')
                for unit_str in f_str:
                    unit=float(unit_str)
                    l.append(unit)
            bad_filename = False
        except IOError:
            print("Error: The file was not found: ", filename)
        #print(l)
    condition=True

    while condition==True:
        print('1- open\n','2- maximum')
        x=input("Enter the choice")
        menu(x,l)

main()
```

from the bottom function i can get list and i can get the user input and i can get the data and move it in second function but it wont work after that.thank you

Comment: i didnt mean to put return (make_table(l)), i have make_table only and the make_table is working fine.

Comment: Assuming this is Python 3.x, there's no way `x` will ever be equal to any number, because `input` returns a _string_, and the string `"1"` is not equal to the integer `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is simple, and has nothing to do with how you're passing values between functions.

In `main`, you're reading a value from the user like this:

```
x=input("Enter the choice")
```

The [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function:

> … reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So, if the user types `1` at the prompt, you get back the string `"1"`.

Now, you pass that value—perfectly correctly—to `menu`.

In `menu`, you then try to compare it to various numbers, like this:

```
if x == 1:
```

But this will never be true. A string, like `"1"`, is *never* equal to a number, like `1`. They're not even the same *kind* of value, much less the same value.

So, you need to do one of two things:

- Convert the input to an number. For example, change `menu(x,l)` to `menu(int(x), l)`. OR…
- Write `menu` to expect strings. For example, change `if x == 1:` to `if x == "1":`.

---

You may be wondering why that `print (x)` didn't help you debug the problem.

`print(x)` prints out the end-user-friendly string representation of whatever you give it. That is, it automatically calls the [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function for you. For debugging purposes, you often want to use [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) instead of `str`, to get the programmer-friendly string representation instead of the end-user-friendly string representation.

For example, `print(str("10"))` will print out `10`—just like `print(str(10))`, so you can't tell them apart. But `print(repr("10"))` will print out `'10'`, unlike `print(repr(10))`, while prints `10`, so you *can* tell them apart. `repr` can also help you spot things like strings with invisible characters in them, having special "node" objects from a parser instead of just strings, etc.